# LPTHW - .format() issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have this error : tuple index out of range

I understand perfectly why there is this error, because I am calling for 3 variables {} {} {} and in my .format() I only put 1 value.

But this value is a function, and so far we have been used to using value such as int, str, etc

Btw, I'm coding in Python 3.7, so how could I make it work under this version of Python? Thanks

```
print("Let's practise everything.")
print('You\'d need to know \'bout espaces with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.')

poem = """
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
"""

print("-----------")
print(poem)
print("-----------")

five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
print("This should be five: {}".format(five))

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return(jelly_beans, jars, crates)

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print("With a starting point of: {}".format(start_point))
print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, {} crates.".format(beans, jars, crates))

start_point = start_point / 10

print("We can also do that this way:")
print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, and {} crates.".format(secret_formula(start_point))))
```

Comment: You need to unpack the results, eg: `format(*secret_formula(start_point))`...

Comment: Thank you so much ! I did not know this, I will read about it ;) 

Thanks again !!